# Which Kernel version does Ubuntu Install on 11.10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, kernel

On a clean install which kernel comes with 11.10? And if possible which other distros have the same or similar one so I can test a hardware failure I keep having on a clean install.

Update: I didn't want to bother people with weird messages (plus a solution on a clean install isn't usually easy to implement), but for popular demand here is my friend's screen capture:

[image]

Update 2 : Also I could rephrase the question with the specific problem, but this question is more useful for everyone.

Comment: there is no ubuntu 10.11, normally ubuntu versions are released in april and october, and end with .04 or .10. Do you mean 11.10? Also, you might want to mention what hardware/error message in the question itself, so you can get an answer to the actual problem you face as well as work on solving it yourself

Comment: When you say "a similar one" are you intending to try installing another distribution in order to see if you have the same error?

Comment: I would suggest you kernel debug messages so we can help you solve the problem directly. Distros normally apply their own patches and use different options, so even if it's the same version, the kernel can still be drastically different. However, if you're able to find a working kernel, it is mostly likely compatible. I noticed that Ubuntu don't normally remove old kernels (at least for a while), so can you choose a different one during boot?

Comment: When you say "a similar one" are you intending to try installing another distribution in order to see if you have the same error? // Yes

Comment: @billc.cn the OP states a clean install, no earlier kernels will be present.

Comment: the specific error looks a LOT like this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_Check_Exception and that would be a start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 11.10 brings kernel 3.0 (including it's updates, off course).

You could try a beta version of Fedora 16, which brings kernel 3.1 (but note that 3.1 was not officially released yet).

Also note that 2.6.39 was the version before 3.0 and don't be fooled by the major version difference: **Linux 3.0 == Linux 2.6.40**

Answer (score 3):

The screenshot you posted has the kernel version - 3.0.0-12-generic

Anyway, what you could do is:

1. Boot the machine from a live CD/USB and get it connected to the internet.
2. From a terminal within the live CD environment, mount your root partition.
3. chroot to the directory that you've mounted your partition in and try running 'apt-get update' and 'apt-get upgrade' from there.
4. Reboot and hopefully there'll have been a kernel/module tweak released in the last week or so that will fix whatever problem your friend is having.

(Probably needs a bit of refinement, but this should give you somewhere to start).

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 10.10 ships with Linux kernel 2.6.35. The kernel is now at version 3.x, so you may want to `sudo apt-get update` in the terminal

Comment: And apt-get upgrade obviously...

Comment: It's a clean install that never reachs an usable shell